# How to set default all checked for some choice in PHP

Tags: php, html, plugins

I use Plugin **Paid Member Subscriptions** in my WP website.

I create some **Subscription Plans** like this image:
[image]

I want to set default checked for all plan like this image:
[image]

What code should I add the following script :

```
<div class="pms-meta-box-field-wrapper">
    <label class="pms-meta-box-field-label"><?php _e( 'Subscription Plans', 'paid-member-subscriptions' ); ?></label>

    <?php
    $subscription_plans = pms_get_subscription_plans();
    $selected_subscription_plans = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pms-content-restrict-subscription-plan' );
    ?>

    <?php if( !empty( $subscription_plans ) ): foreach( $subscription_plans as $subscription_plan ): ?>

        <label class="pms-meta-box-checkbox-label" for="pms-content-restrict-subscription-plan-<?php echo $subscription_plan->id ?>">
            <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $subscription_plan->id; ?>" <?php if( in_array( $subscription_plan->id, $selected_subscription_plans ) ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> name="pms-content-restrict-subscription-plan[]" id="pms-content-restrict-subscription-plan-<?php echo $subscription_plan->id ?>">
            <?php echo $subscription_plan->name; ?>
        </label>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
        <p class="description"><?php echo __( 'Members subscribed to these Subscription plans will be able to view this page.', 'paid-member-subscriptions' ); ?></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="description"><?php printf( __( 'You do not have any active Subscription Plans yet. Please create them <a href="%s">here</a>', 'paid-member-subscriptions' ), admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=pms-subscription' ) ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>

(source: .../wp-content/plugins/paid-member-subscriptions/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/view-meta-box-single-content-restriction.php)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add checked in your input tag

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the following line

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $subscription_plan->id; ?>" <?php if( in_array( $subscription_plan->id, $selected_subscription_plans ) ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> name="pms-content-restrict-subscription-plan[]" id="pms-content-restrict-subscription-plan-<?php echo $subscription_plan->id ?>">
```

to this

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $subscription_plan->id; ?>" checked name="pms-content-restrict-subscription-plan[]" id="pms-content-restrict-subscription-plan-<?php echo $subscription_plan->id ?>">
```

The whole if clause has been replace with just the word checked